Guest VM Unable to Access External Networks Despite Host Connectivity with Bridge Network
I am using AlmaLinux with WHM installed, both updated to the latest versions. This VM is hosted on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS using Virt Manager. After configuring the bridge network, the host can access the internet and successfully ping its gateway (103.192.157.241) and nameserver (103.84.36.5).
However, the VM is unable to ping its gateway (103.192.157.241) or nameserver (103.84.36.5). It can only ping the host IP address (103.192.157.246). Additionally, the VM cannot communicate with external networks — for example, it cannot ping 8.8.8.8, perform system updates/upgrades, or be accessed via a browser.
Despite these issues, the host can access the VM via SSH using the terminal.
Below are the details of the host:
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eno1]
      addresses: [103.192.157.246/28]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 103.192.157.241
      nameservers:
        addresses: [103.84.36.5]
      macaddress: 00:1e:67:ad:ec:76
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:67:ad:ec:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:67:ad:ec:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:67:ad:ec:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 103.192.157.246/28 brd 103.192.157.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::382e:ddff:fe6e:5175/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:32:32:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:48:35:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:48:4e:74:e1:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc48:4eff:fe74:e186/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip route
default via 103.192.157.241 dev br0 proto static 
103.192.157.240/28 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 103.192.157.246 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 

$ sudo iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 386K packets, 218M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 386K  218M LIBVIRT_INP  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   88  5692 LIBVIRT_FWX  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   88  5692 LIBVIRT_FWI  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   88  5692 LIBVIRT_FWO  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   88  5692 ACCEPT     0    --  br0    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  br0    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  br0    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  br0    eno1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  eno1   br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            103.192.157.245      state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  *      eno1    103.192.157.240/28   0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            103.192.157.240/28  

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 309K packets, 77M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 309K   77M LIBVIRT_OUT  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 REJECT     0    --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     0    --  *      virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     0    --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     0    --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  virbr1 virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     17   --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     17   --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     17   --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     17   --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     17   --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     17   --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:68
    0     0 ACCEPT     17   --  *      virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  *      virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     17   --  *      virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  *      virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:68

$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1268 packets, 115K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    7   284 DNAT       6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            103.192.157.246      tcp dpt:80 to:103.192.157.245:80

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 55141 packets, 7822K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
55146 7825K LIBVIRT_PRT  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      eno1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      eno1    103.192.157.240/28   0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LIBVIRT_PRT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   365 RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24        
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255     
    0     0 MASQUERADE  6    --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  17   --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24 

$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.001e67adec76   no      eno1
                            eth0
                            tap0
virbr0      8000.52540032320d   yes     
virbr1      8000.525400483532   yes

$ lsmod | grep tap
tap                    28672  1 vhost_net

$ virsh net-list --all
 Name       State    Autostart   Persistent
---------------------------------------------
 default    active   yes         yes
 isolated   active   yes         yes

$ virsh --connect qemu:///session domiflist WHM
 Interface   Type     Source   Model    MAC
-----------------------------------------------------------
 tap0        bridge   br0      virtio   52:54:00:de:68:11

Below are the details of the VM:
[root@server1 ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:de:68:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 103.192.157.245/28 brd 103.192.157.255 scope global noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fede:6811/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[root@server1 ~]# ip route
default via 103.192.157.241 dev enp1s0 proto static metric 100 
103.192.157.240/28 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 103.192.157.245 metric 100 

VM XML
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:de:68:11"/>
  <source bridge="br0"/>
  <target dev="tap0"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>

